# Redirect user to a custom url after logged in

Tags: php, username, template-redirect

I'm using "Passwordless Login with OTP / SMS & Email - Facebook Account Kit" for login.

I want to redirect user to `http://www.domain.com/author/<username>/screen` after they log in

this is the code I used

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $redirect = ('http://www.domain.com/author/'.$current_user->user_login.'/screen'); }
```

It redirect to `http://www.domain.com/author/screen` without the username. can anyone help me with this

Answer (score 0):

```
function login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ){
    $URL ="http://www.abcgg.com";
    return $URL;
}
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `wp_get_current_user()` is not available until after pluggable is run.  Try adding your code to a later hook:

```
add_action( 'wp_login', function () {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $redirect = ('http://www.domain.com/author/'.$current_user->user_login.'/screen'); 
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you for the answer I tried with this code but now it redirects to "https://www.domain.com/wp-admin/

Comment: try adding `wp_die($redirect);` to help debug what may be the issue